# textbox's value not correct when displayed in browser

Tags: asp.net

I have a simple textbox on my page with an embedded code block where I set its value. But in the browser it still displays "oldvalue". Can't figure out why..

```
<asp:TextBox id="textBox" runat="server" Text="oldvalue">
</asp:TextBox>     

<%
    var box = FindControl("textBox") as TextBox;
    box.Text = "newvalue";
%>
```

Comment: Removed the classic ASP tag. ASP.NET <> ASP. And you should also not use it in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work as the inline expressions `<% %>` are executed after `prerender` event  in the asp.net page life cycle.

And the last changes you can make to the contents of the page or its controls is upto `PreRender` event, So that any changes in the view state of the server control can be saved during this event. ***[MSDN reference here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28VS.100%29.aspx)***

So, rather than using inline expressions, use any event upto `PreRender` events of Page life cycle in your code to change the `TextBox.Text` property.